# Windows command line, how to filter with pipe

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, grep

I'm trying to filter ping stats in windows command line using pipe. What I want is to get the 'time' of each ping.

```
"ping -n 1 -w 1000 " + ip
```

prints

```
Pinging 216.52.241.254 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.52.241.254: bytes=32 time=82ms TTL=240

Ping statistics for 216.52.241.254:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 82ms, Maximum = 82ms, Average = 82ms
```

The output I'm looking for from that would just be `82`.

and my attempt with findstr `"ping -n 1 -w 1000 " + ip + ' | findstr time=[0-9]*'` prints:

```
Reply from 216.52.241.254: bytes=32 time=83ms TTL=240
```

The output should just be `83` this time.

I've tried using grep `?("time=")[0-9]*ms` but on top of that line probably not being right I don't think windows grep includes conditionals

Comment: please edit your questoin to include your required output. If you do have a grep in your path the `-o` option may give you what you want, but I can't be sure, so please edit Q with required output. Good luck.

Comment: Why not use find to get the line which includes `time=` and then use the `for` statement to parse this ? But this will only work for a Windows with English locale. Perhaps it is better to use a more high level language and write some pinging code (perhaps even wsh might be able to do so: http://larsmichelsen.com/vbs/quickie-how-to-ping-a-host-in-vbs-i-got-two-ways/). And by the way: my Windows 7 does not include a `grep` command

Comment: I think I'd like to avoid playing with sockets if I can haha. I'll look into the for statement

Comment: best to add a Powershell tag to this, PS can certainly do this. Good luck.